# Why not a setter return the object itself?

Tags: design-patterns

The setter, a method to set the instance variable, will return nothing/null in many programming languages.

I wonder why can't it return the object itself?

```
# from this
def set_x(x):
    _x = x

# to this
def set_x(x):
    _x = x
    return self
```

Returning `self` in setters could make it easier for method chaining (fluent interface):

```py
# Python-like pseudo-code
# from this
data = (
    data
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
)
data.set_x("X")
data.set_y("Y")

# to this
data = (
    data
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    .set_x("X")
    .set_y("Y")
)
```

Is there any drawback for this design? Why does no language change its design?

Comment: It could, and many APIs do this.

Comment: I wonder why no language changes to this design. Why not being a standard feature? In recent decades, languages update their design and implementation for syntactic sugar, but no one adopts fluent interface with setter, why?

Comment: “No one”? This is a common pattern across languages and libraries—whether or not someone **chooses** it is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the drawbacks of this approach. Moreover, it will allow you to switch to immutable objects easier. Basically, instead of setting `x` , you will be able to return a new instance of the object that uses the new x to copy the unchanged y:

```
def set_x(x):
    return Point(x, self._y)
```

If you follow this path, I would go as far as stepping away from the *setter* pattern and using a name like `with_x(new_x)` or simply `x(new_x)` instead.

There are articles that question the classic pattern of getters and setters, if you want to read more about this, here are some links:
[Are Getters And Setters an Anti-Pattern?](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/are-getters-and-setters-an-anti-pattern-c8cb5625ca8c?sk=79b92a15fd60dc424f33c12e84ccb39a) and
[Getters/Setters. Evil. Period.](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html)

Comment: Tangential, but that’s not the best article to discuss this topic. It conflates naming with functionality, but more importantly it doesn’t address the OP’s question at all, which is more about fluent interfaces. Naming is important, but orthogonal to the question.

Comment: I agree - perhaps I've jumped from one idea to another too quickly. my point is that, once you consider moving away from the traditional setter, you might as well consider taking it one step further and avoid mutability altogether, while keeping the fluent API.

Comment: Mutability seems like a separate issue as well (and at what level), although immutability is a good goal  Whether it not it’s practical depends on context, unfortunately :)